# How can I pass the for loop variable to c in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, evaluate

I want to pass the `for` loop variable to page.evaluate in puppeteer, in order to get the all gages of a gallery. But it doesn't work. It always reports `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed`.

The following is a example of my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath:'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('D:\\Code Workplace\\Javascripts\\TurnPage\\index.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        await page.evaluateHandle((index) => {
            $('.flipbook').turn('page', index);
        }, index);
    }
    await sleep(300);
    await page.emulateMedia('print');
    await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

So I need help to pass the loop variable to variable. Dose anyone met this problem before? Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I tested the page it throw 2 errors in puppeteer:

1. Without waiting jQuery and turn.js plugin loaded

   > Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
2. `index` have to start from `1` not `0` or

   > Error: Evaluation failed: TurnJsError

Fixed code:

```
await page.waitForFunction('typeof(jQuery) == "function" && typeof($().turn) == "function"', {
  timeout: 5000
});

for (let index = 1; index < 8; index++) {
  await page.evaluateHandle((index) => {
    $('.flipbook').turn('page', index);
  }, index);

  //await sleep(2000); // for debugging
}
```

Comment: I think the point is not whether the turn.js was loaded. Because it was executed after page.goto, and when I used `await page.evaluateHandle((index) => {$('.flipbook').turn('page', 2)});`, it worked.

Comment: I have tried to run this action for many times, it also worked. Why do you think it would fail by running several times? If the single action worked, it doesn't mean the function is already been loaded?

Comment: in my environment sometimes it work because jQuery loaded in cache, have you tried code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your code. But it seems like stucking in the loop and cannot finish. I also tried to set `page.setCacheEnabled` to `false`, and the single action is still worked.

Comment: Of course, You can use this [link](http://www.kaol.org/TurnPage/) to run some test.

Comment: Wow, I don't believe I just make such a silly mistake. I forgot the function's args limits. Thanks a lot.